# How to send ISO message Object from client to Netty server in java

Tags: java, netty

Actually i can send and receive String object with netty but i can not send any object like ISO message and i can not find the reason for that .
this is start method in client

```
public void start() {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap().group(group)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ClientAdapterInitializer());

        Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(server, port).sync().channel();

        channel.write("Hi\n");


        IsoMessage o = new IsoMessage();
        o.setType(0200);
        o.setBinary(true);
        Teacher t = new Teacher(1, "hhhhh");
        //ObjectEncoder encoder = new ObjectEncoder();
        o.setField(3, new IsoValue(IsoType.BINARY, group, 1100));
        channel.write(t);
        channel.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //  group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

and in server `@Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        IsoMessage is=(IsoMessage) msg;
        System.out.println(""+is.getType());
        //ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) is;
        //System.out.println(""+byteBuf.toString());
        //logger.info("message : {} " + 
        //byteBuf.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()));
        channels.writeAndFlush(msg);
    }`

Comment: How does your pipeline look?

Comment: till now i didn't provide it

Answer (score 0):

You should check what the `ChannelFuture` of the `write` is telling you. It will most likely be failed with an exception that will tell you more why it not worked